# Unable to add a class

Tags: jquery

On click of the Addons Button , and selection and unselection of checkboxes , a specific class namely
ui-checkbox-on and ui-checkbox-off is added dynamically to the label element .

This is my code

```js
$(document).on('click', '.remove', function (e) {
    $("#addonsWrap").find("label.ui-checkbox-on").removeClass('ui-checkbox-on');   
});
```

```css
.pageMidLogo {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
}
.createAccountWrap {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    height:auto;
    padding:20px;
}
.createAccountWrap .h3_head {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 25px !important;
}
.iLabel {
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 16px;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
.insideInput {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
.tooltipIcon {
    width: 27px;
    height: 27px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 8px;
    top: 16px;
    background: #ababab;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
.tooltipIcon:before {
    font-size: 19px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    color:#fff;
}
.pop_tooltipIcon {
    font-size: 36px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color:#d03e43;
}
.iconPinReload {
    /*background: url(../images/icon-capthareload.png) 10px 10px no-repeat #f6f6f6;
 border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
 width: 52px;
 height: 41px;*/
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    right: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 15px;
}
/*.iconPinReload:hover{
 background: url(../images/icon-capthareload.png) 10px 10px no-repeat #f0f0f0;
}*/
 .tpMenuWrap {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    width: 88%;
}
.btMenuWrap {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    width: 88%;
}
.ul_menu {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    width:100%;
    list-style:none;
}
.ul_menu li {
    padding: 10px 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 24px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
.ul_menu li a {
    font-weight: 500;
    color:#ddd;
}
.ul_menu li a:hover {
    color:#fff;
}
.panelCloseBtn {
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #777 !important;
}
.panelCloseBtn:hover {
    color: #999 !important;
}
.homeListMenuWrap {
    padding:0px !important;
    margin:0px;
    width:100%;
    list-style:none;
}
.homeListMenuWrap li {
    padding:25px 25px 20px 25px;
    margin:0px;
    width:100%;
    list-style:none;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
}
.homeListMenuWrap li a:hover {
    color:#d03e43;
}
.homeListMenuWrap li .qrcode {
    background:url(../images/icon-QRcode.png) left top no-repeat;
    padding-left: 120px;
    display: block;
    color:#314158;
    min-height:110px;
}
.homeListMenuWrap li .homedeliver {
    background:url(../images/icon-homedelivery.png) left top no-repeat;
    padding-left: 120px;
    display: block;
    color:#314158;
    min-height:110px;
}
.homeListMenuWrap li .qrcode p, .homeListMenuWrap li .homedeliver p {
    font-size:15px;
}
.qrcode_errorWrap {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    height:auto;
    padding:20px;
}
.qrcode_errorWrap .qrcodeError {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    font-size:26px !important;
    margin-bottom: 25px !important;
    font-weight: 400 !important;
}
.orDivider {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 22px !important;
    font-style: italic;
    position:relative;
    margin: 25px 0;
}
.orDivider span {
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 0 15px;
}
.orDivider .hr {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
}
/* Tree Menu Start */
 .TreeMenu {
    width:100%;
}
.TreeMenu .ui-collapsible-heading {
    margin:0px !important;
}
.TreeMenu .ui-collapsible-heading a {
    border-left:0px;
    border-right:0px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #e6e6e6;
    border-top:1px solid #e6e6e6;
    border-radius: 0px;
}
.TreeMenu .ui-collapsible-heading-toggle {
    font-size:20px;
}
.TreeMenu .ui-collapsible-content {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    border: 0px !important;
    background: #fff;
}
.TreeMenu_Content {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    padding: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.TreeMenu_Content .lastItm_Wrap {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    height:auto;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
.TreeMenu_Content .lastItm_Wrap .Itm_left_aside {
    width:60%;
    float:left;
}
.TreeMenu_Content .lastItm_Wrap .Itm_dtsl {
    width:75%;
    float:left;
}
.TreeMenu_Content .lastItm_Wrap .Itm_dtsl .vegLabel {
    background:url(../images/veg_labels.png) left 3px no-repeat;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
.TreeMenu_Content .lastItm_Wrap .Itm_dtsl .nonvegLabel {
    background:url(../images/nonveg_labels.png) left 3px no-repeat;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
.TreeMenu_Content .lastItm_Wrap .Itm_dtsl h3 {
    font-size:16px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    position:relative;
    padding-right: 50px;
}
.TreeMenu_Content .lastItm_Wrap .Itm_dtsl h3 .prdDiscription {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 1px;
    width: auto !important;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 0px 8px;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.TreeMenu_Content .lastItm_Wrap .Itm_dtsl .addonsList {
    font-size: 14px;
    opacity: 0.7;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
.TreeMenu_Content .lastItm_Wrap .Itm_img {
    width:74px;
    height:74px;
    float:left;
    background:#ddd;
    margin-right:10px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.TreeMenu_Content .lastItm_Wrap .Itm_img img {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    border:0px;
}
.TreeMenu_Content .lastItm_Wrap .Itm_right_aside {
    width:30%;
    float:right;
    text-align:right;
}
.TreeMenu_Content .lastItm_Wrap .Itm_right_aside .trashBtn {
    font-size:20px;
}
.TreeMenu_Content .lastItm_Wrap .Itm_right_aside p {
    font-size:16px;
}
.TreeMenu_Content .lastItm_Wrap .Itm_right_aside p strike {
    margin-right:10px;
}
.TreeMenu_Content .lastItm_Wrap .Itm_right_aside p b {
    font-weight:600;
}
/* Tree Child */
 .TreeMenuChild .ui-collapsible-content {
    padding:0px;
}
.TreeMenuChild .ui-icon-plus:after {
    background-image: url(images/icons-png/carat-r-black.png) !important;
}
.TreeMenuChild .ui-icon-minus:after {
    background-image: url(images/icons-png/carat-d-white.png) !important;
    background-color:#d03e43;
}
.TreeMenuChild .ui-collapsible-heading-toggle {
    background-color:#fff !important;
    font-size:18px;
}
.TreeMenuChild .ui-collapsible-heading-toggle:last-child {
    margin-top:-1px;
}
.addonsBtn {
    width: auto !important;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    border-radius: 20px !important;
    font-size:13px;
}
.addonsBtn a {
    color:#333 !important;
}
.Itm_discrp {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    height:auto;
    margin-top:10px;
}
.Itm_discrp h3 {
    margin-bottom: 10px !important;
    padding: 0px;
}
.Itm_discrp p {
    text-align: justify;
}
.Qty_Wrap {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}
.Qty_Wrap .QtyBtn {
    float: left;
    width: 33px;
    border-radius: 34px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.Qty_Wrap .QtyBtn:before {
    margin-top:4px;
}
.Qty_Wrap .ui-input-text {
    float: left;
    border: 0px;
    box-shadow: none;
    background: #fff;
    width: 50px;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px 2px 0px 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
.Qty_Wrap .QtyInput {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 1.6em;
}
.addonsContent h2 {
    font-size:18px;
}
.addonsContent .rightAction {
    float: right;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-top: -28px;
}
.addonsContent .rightAction a {
    padding-right:20px;
}
.addonsContent .rightAction a.tick {
    font-size: 22px;
    padding-right:0px;
}
.addonsContent .rightAction a.remove {
    color:#333;
    opacity:0.7;
}
.addonsContent .addonsQtyWrap {
    width:100%;
    padding: 0 15px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
.addonsContent .addonsQtyWrap ul {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
}
.addonsContent .addonsQtyWrap ul li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.addonsContent .addonsQtyWrap ul li:hover {
    background:#eee;
}
.addonsContent .addonsQtyWrap ul li.active {
    border:1px solid #d03e43;
    color:#d03e43;
}
.addonsContent .popup_content_addonsWrap {
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
    overflow:auto;
}
.addonsContent .addonsListWrap {
    width:100%;
}
.addonsContent .addonsListWrap h3 {
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.addonsContent .addonsListWrap ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.addonsContent .addonsListWrap ul li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.addonsContent .addonsListWrap ul li form {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    height: auto;
    display: -webkit-inline-box;
}
.addonsContent .addonsListWrap ul li .ui-mini {
    margin: 0px;
}
.addonsContent .addonsListWrap ul li .ui-mini label {
    background:#fff !important;
    border:0px;
    margin-left:-5px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.myOrderPanel_footer {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    bottom:0px;
    left: 0px;
    position:fixed;
    background:rgba(208, 62, 67, 0.9);
    border-top:2px solid #d03e43;
    padding:10px;
    color:#fff;
    z-index:999;
}
.myOrderPanel_footer:hover {
    background:rgba(208, 62, 67, 1);
}
.myOrderPanel_footer .myOrderPanel_inner {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
.myOrderPanel_footer .myOrderPanel_inner:after {
    content:'\e988';
    font-family:"fontello";
    display: inline-block;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    font-size: 37px;
    position:absolute;
}
.myOrderPanel_footer .myOrderPanel_inner .myorders, .myOrderPanel_footer .myOrderPanel_inner .subtotal {
    float:left;
}
.myOrderPanel_footer .myOrderPanel_inner .myorders {
    padding: 12px 0px;
    font-size:18px;
    margin-right:10px;
}
.myOrderPanel_footer .myOrderPanel_inner .myorders i {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    padding: 7px;
    border-radius: 120px;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-right:15px;
}
.myOrderPanel_footer .myOrderPanel_inner .subtotal {
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-top:4px;
}
.myOrderPanel_footer .myOrderPanel_inner .subtotal b {
    font-size:16px;
}
.myOrderPanel_footer .myOrderPanel_inner .subtotal b span {
    font-size:22px;
}
.myOrderPanel_footer .myOrderPanel_inner .subtotal .minOrder {
    font-size:13px;
    opacity:0.7;
}
/*.myOrderPanel_footer .myOrderPanel_right{
 width:85%;
 float:left;
 padding-left: 12px;
}*/

/*.myOrderPanel_footer .myOrderPanel_right .subtotal{
 font-size:18px;
}
.myOrderPanel_footer .myOrderPanel_right .subtotal span{
 margin-left:10px;
 font-size:24px;
}
.myOrderPanel_footer .myOrderPanel_right .subtotal i{
 width:100%;
 float:left;
 font-size:13px;
 font-style:normal;
}*/

/* My Order page start */
 .MyOrdersPage {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    height:auto;
}
.MyOrdersPage .TreeMenu_Content .lastItm_Wrap {
    border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.vendorNameDtsl {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    height:auto;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
    padding:10px 20px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
}
.vendorNameDtsl h6 {
    font-size: 16px;
    float: left;
    margin:0px !important;
    padding-top:4px !important;
}
.vendorNameDtsl span {
    font-size: 14px;
    float: right;
    padding:2px 20px;
    border:1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-radius: 20px;
}
.orderSummary_priceDtsl {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    height:auto;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.orderSummary_priceDtsl li {
    list-style:none;
    text-align:right;
    font-size:16px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.orderSummary_priceDtsl li span {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    float: right;
}
.orderSummary_priceDtsl li.totalsection {
    padding-top:17px;
    border-top:2px solid #ddd;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#d03e43;
    margin-top:20px;
}
/*.orderSummary_priceDtsl .inclusiveTax{
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
 margin:30px 0px !important;
}*/
 .customerNameDtl {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    height:auto;
    padding:0 20px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
.customerNameDtl_left {
    font-size:16px;
    line-height:26px;
    width:auto;
    text-align:left;
    float:left;
}
.customerNameDtl_right {
    float:right;
    width:auto;
    text-align:right;
}
.customerNameDtl_right .totalsection {
    font-size:20px !important;
    color:#d03e43;
}
.customerNameDtl_right .totalsection span {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.customerNameDtl_right button {
    padding:8px;
    font-size:17px;
}
/* My Order page end */
 .placeorderimg {
    width:176px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding-bottom:50px;
}
.cancelOrder {
    width: 100% !important;
    float: left;
    padding: 18px 0px !important;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.commentWrap {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    height:auto;
    margin:15px 0px;
}
.commentWrap textarea {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    height:90px;
    margin:15px 0px;
    padding:15px;
}
```

```html
          <div class="TreeMenu_Content">
                                                <div class="lastItm_Wrap">
                                                    <div class="Itm_left_aside">
                                                        <div class="Itm_img"></div>
                                                        <div class="Itm_dtsl">
                                                            <button class="btn-d addonsBtn ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all"><a href="#addonsWrap" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="addonsWrap" aria-expanded="false" class="ui-link">Addons</a></button>
                                                            <div class="Itm_discrp">
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
    <div data-role="popup" id="addonsWrap" class="ui-content ui-popup ui-body-a ui-overlay-shadow ui-corner-all" data-theme="a">
            <div class="popup_inner addonsContent">
                <div class="popup_header">
                    <h2>Addons</h2>
                    <div class="rightAction">
                        <a href="#" class="remove ui-link">Remove All</a>
                        <a href="#" class="icon-ok-1 tick ui-link"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="addonsQtyWrap">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="active">Qty-1</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="popup_content">
                    <div class="popup_content_addonsWrap">
                        <div class="addonsListWrap">
                            <h3>Toppings</h3>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <form>
                                        <div class="ui-checkbox ui-mini"><label for="checkbox-mini-0" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off">Topping items </label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-mini-0" id="checkbox-mini-0" data-mini="true"/></div>
                                    </form>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="addonsListWrap" style="margin-top:10px;">
                            <h3>Crust</h3>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <form>
                                        <div class="ui-checkbox ui-mini"><label for="checkbox-mini-4" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off">Crust items </label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-mini-0" id="checkbox-mini-4" data-mini="true"/></div>
                                    </form>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
    
            </div>
        </div>
```

Could you please let me know whats the issue ??

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are only removing the class and not unchecking the checkboxes. You can rather trigger click of on checkboxes:

```
$(document).on('click', '.remove', function (e) {
  $("#addonsWrap").find("label.ui-checkbox-on").click();   
});
```

### Working Demo

Comment: Thank you very very much ,  much easier solution .